# Не деплоится Tomcat 10.0.4

Tags: java, tomcat

При попытке сделать деплой сервера (согласно обучающему видео) получаю такие ошибки.

> 21-Apr-2021 13:35:22.679 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
> 21-Apr-2021 13:35:22.873 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
> 21-Apr-2021 13:35:23.047 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [167] milliseconds.
> 21-Apr-2021 13:35:23.049 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/SpringMVC_war_exploded] startup failed due to previous errors
> [2021-04-21 01:35:23,142] Artifact SpringMVC:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.

Проект создан виз архетипа maven-archetype-webapp. Сервер заработал, когда запустио голое приложение, которое было в архетипе
Проблема началась, когда я объявил файл  dispatcher-servlet.xml (согласно уроку).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.itvdn.controllers"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

Мне кажется, что проблемная строка `<context:component-scan base-package="com.itvdn.controllers"/>.`
При ее удалении, сервер деплоится, но естественно приложение не работает корректно, так как в указанном пути находятся мои контроллеры. Контроллеры лежат в папке java.com.itvdn.controllers
Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Spring не поддерживает tomcat 10 из-за того, что Tomcat 10 использует Jakarta EE 9, где имена пакетов для API-интерфейсов изменены с javax. * На jakarta. *.